# What am I doing wrong in searching for the intersection point between 2 linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

```
y=4x+5
y=3x-7
```

First I take equation 1 and set y to 0:

```
0 = 4x + 5
-5 = 4x
-5/4 = x
```

I get that the information above only tells me what the the coordinate of x is when y hits 0.

Then I pug the x-coordinate into the other function.

```
y = 3(-5/4) - 7
y = -15/4 - 7
y = -10.25
```

But I looked up both of these graphs on Google and something went wrong. was there a mis-step?

EDIT: What I supposed to just set them to equal each other?

Comment: You have figured out that $(-5/4, 0)$ is in the first line, and that $(-5/4, -10.25)$ is in the second line.  Since these aren't the same point, you haven't found an intersection.  Since an intersection point will have the same $y$ value, try solving $4x+5 = 3x-7$

Comment: There is no justification to setting $y=0$. Setting $y=0$ in equation 1 and solving for $x$ is entirely unrelated to equation 2.

Comment: Why do you care where the first line meets the $x$-axis?  Why would that meeting have anything to do with where the two lines meet?  You have discovered that the vertical distance between the two lines is 10.25 units when the first one meets the $x$-axis, but it's not clear why you want to know that.

Comment: Mathematics isn't about "I'm allowed to do this" and "I'm supposed to do that".  That's for lawyers.  Mathematics is about "if I assume this, then I can figure out that".  Think about what you are trying to figure out, and how you can do that, how you will know if you are right.  Suppose I tell you that $(100, 200)$ is a solution.  Am I lying or telling the truth?  How do you know?

Comment: Interesting way of putting it. I just figure out the way to do this with linear equations is to set them equal to each other to find the x and then just pick one to plug that into to find the y, and now I'm trying to figure out if this will work for quadratic equations. I'll have to test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two lines meet, they must meet at some $(x',y')$, and the point $(x',y')$ must be on both lines.

Therefore, let $y'=4x'+5$ and $y'=3x'-7$, leading to

$$4x'+5 = 3x'-7 \\
x' = -12.$$

Plugging this value of $x'$ into either equation, we get

$$y' = 4(-12)+5 = -48+5 = -43.$$

So the lines intersect only at $(x',y') = (-12,-43)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just equate two equations..

Here is my answer

$y=4x+5=3x-7\Rightarrow x=-12\Rightarrow y=-43$

So $(-12,-43)$ is the point of intersection

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's think about what you're doing. In the first part, you're computing what value of $x$ makes $y=0$ in the first equation. So the point $(-5/4,0)$ is on the line $y=4x+5$. Then in the second part, you're just plugging $-5/4$ into the second line, so the point $(-5/4,-10.25)$ is on the line $y=3x-7$. Those are both true, but those don't help us answer the question at hand.

What you want is to find an $x$ where the two $y$ values are equal. So we can set $$ 4x+5 = 3x-7$$ and solve to get $$x = -12.$$